# Need my accordion jump to top when active

Tags: jquery

Some of my accordions have a long content. The title hides above the window and only part of content is visible. I want to slide up to top (until the title is visible).

```js
//Accordion & Toggle
jQuery('.dt-sc-toggle').toggle(function(){
   jQuery(this).addClass('active'); },function(){
      jQuery(this).removeClass('active'); });
        jQuery('.dt-sc-toggle').click(function(){ jQuery(this).next('.dt-sc-toggle-content').slideToggle(); }); 
          jQuery('.dt-sc-toggle-frame-set').each(function(){
            var $this = jQuery(this),
            $toggle = $this.find('.dt-sc-toggle-accordion');
            $toggle.click(function(){
            if( jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
                $this.find('.dt-sc-toggle-accordion').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
                jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
            }
            return false;
        });
        //Activate First Item always
        $this.find('.dt-sc-toggle-accordion:first').addClass("active");
        $this.find('.dt-sc-toggle-accordion:first').next().slideDown();
});//Accordion & Toggle
function animateSection(){
         var applyViewPort = ( jQuery("html").hasClass('csstransforms') ) ? ":in-viewport" : "";
         jQuery('.animate'+applyViewPort).each(function(){
            var $this = jQuery(this),
                $animation = ( $this.data("animation") !== undefined ) ? $this.data("animation") : "slideUp";
            var $delay = ( $this.data("delay") !== undefined ) ? $this.data("delay") : 300;
        if( !$this.hasClass($animation) ){
            setTimeout(function() { $this.addClass($animation); },$delay);
        }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a live demo? It will help us to understand the problem.